# Reading JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file and i have to read data from this file when the page loads. I suspect there is something wrong with my JSON Structure. JSONLint is showing that it is valid. So i must be using the wrong method to access it.

It is basically an array of objects (or that is what i think).

```
{"Listings":[
{"Listing1":
    {
        "agency_code":"BP",
        "property_code":"BON1",
        "Property_GUID":"6dded624",
        "FileNo /":"",
        "country":"AUSTRALIA",
        "state":"New South Wales",
        "subregion /":""
            }
        },
   {"Listing1":
    {
        "agency_code":"BPGA",
        "property_code":"BONNSTG4-Lot11",
        "Property_GUID":"6dded624-cde2-429a-81d4-bd6f91256345",
        "FileNo /":"",
        "country":"AUSTRALIA",
        "state":"New South Wales",
        "subregion /":""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the $.ajax to read the JSON. The file is loading successfully. Now how do i access the individual "listings" and how to measure how many Listings are present in total?
I tried the $.each to loop through the array but my code is not working.

Comment: It's not an array of objects, it's an object, with a single property called `Listings`, that contains the array of objects you probably want to iterate over. It's impossible to tell unless you show the code that does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an array of objects, but that array is not the first tier, it's stored in the top-level `Listings` property.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function (response) {
        for (var i = 0, len = response.Listings.length; i < len; i++) {
            //You can now access individual properties like this:
            var agencyCode = response.Listings[i].Listing1.agency_code;
        }
    }
});
```

This `for` loop will perform faster than jQuery's `.each()` or `$.each()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/btHy5/1/

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. I am using `len = response.Listings.length` in the `for` loop. In your code you don't really need to get the total number of rows since you are using `$.each()`.

Comment: I meant to answer the OP's question ` how to measure how many Listings are present in total`

Comment: It seems i am in the right path. Previously my code is
`$(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  datatype: 'JSON',
  url: 'scripts/Listing.json',
  success: processJSON
  });
  
  function processJSON(data) {
    $.each(data.Listings,function(i,item) {
     console.log(data.Listings.length);
    });
   }
 });`

It is giving me different errors in different browser. Chrome is showing that it cant find length property for undefined.

Comment: @Sparda In general when you are debugging code like this, start by doing a `console.log(data)`, then a `console.log(data.Listings);`. Work from what you know to be true toward the error you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: Nevermind, its working. The errors are due to Chrome's cache. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jasper I have an issue with the above code. when we say  
`var agencyCode = response.Listings[i].Listing1.agency_code`, we are referring to the agency_code in Listing1. But when the for loop executes second time, it will be  
`var agencyCode = response.Listings[1].Listing1.agency_code`  
But there is no `Listing1` in `Listings[1]`. How do i access the agency_code of `Listing2` within the loop?

Comment: @Sparda `var agencyCode = response.Listings[i]['Listing' + (i + 1)].agency_code` should do the trick, adding the index to the property name. The `(i + 1)` is so it starts with one instead of zero. If you control the output of the JSON this is unnecessary, because each listing is an index in the array, so there is no need to give each listing a unique property name.